# react-native find screen the was idle to logout

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I have tried panResponder to check the screen idle. but it doesn't work. i am not sure, what mistake i done.

```
  const timerId = useRef(false)
  const [timeForInactivityInSecond, setTimeForInactivityInSecond] = useState(
    1000
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    resetInactivityTimeout()
  }, [])

  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
        // console.log('user starts touch');
        resetInactivityTimeout()
      },
    })
  ).current

  const resetInactivityTimeout = () => {
    clearTimeout(timerId.current)
    timerId.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("amss")
      // action after user has been detected idle
    }, timeForInactivityInSecond * 1000)
  }
```

In react-native we have multiple screen. so how can we find that the screen is idle to logout the session. Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple screens, you can add the same logic in StackScreen where all the screens are added (if you are using react-navigation).

Rather than adding the logic to all the screen, add the timeout logic in master component which holds all the other screens.

If you are using PanResponder, add the pan Responder to Parent View.

```
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      <NavigationContainer>
      {/* Rest of your app code */}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  )
```